# Trying to fix segmentation fault in a C program

Tags: c

I am a student and I got this program which I have been working on for a week. I got this segmentation fault problem every time I run this program, I changed and tried almost everything, read a lot on the internet and nothing helped. I have been trying to solve this with and without a debugger!

I think it's in the way I allocated the memory in `eurovisionAddState()`, but I changed it many times, nothing worked...

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_OF_JUDGE_VOTES 10
#define NOT_FOUND -1

typedef enum eurovisionResult_t {
    EUROVISION_NULL_ARGUMENT,
    EUROVISION_OUT_OF_MEMORY,
    EUROVISION_INVALID_ID,
    EUROVISION_INVALID_NAME,
    EUROVISION_STATE_ALREADY_EXIST,
    EUROVISION_STATE_NOT_EXIST,
    EUROVISION_JUDGE_ALREADY_EXIST,
    EUROVISION_JUDGE_NOT_EXIST,
    EUROVISION_SAME_STATE,
    EUROVISION_SUCCESS
} EurovisionResult;

//Structs:
struct country_t {
    int *ID;
    char *CountryName;
    char *SongName;
};

typedef struct country_t *Country;

//Nodes
typedef struct CountryNode_t {
    Country data;
    struct CountryNode_t *next;
    struct CountryNode_t *before;
} *CountryNode;

typedef struct eurovision_t {
    CountryNode Countries;
} *Eurovision;

//========
//Functions:
Eurovision eurovisionCreate() {
    Eurovision euro = (Eurovision)malloc(sizeof(*euro));
    euro->Countries = (CountryNode)malloc(sizeof(struct CountryNode_t));
    return euro;
}

static Eurovision setupEurovision() {
    Eurovision eurovision = eurovisionCreate();
    assert(eurovision);
    return eurovision;
}

CountryNode countryGetFirst(CountryNode cn) {
    while (cn->before) {
        cn = cn->before;
    }
    return cn;
}

bool countryNodeExists(CountryNode c, int ID) //Returns TRUE if country with the given ID exists,
{                                            // and FALSE if country with the given ID doesn't exist
    CountryNode cn = countryGetFirst(c);
    while (cn) {
        if (*(cn->data->ID) == ID) {
            return true;
        }
        cn = cn->next;
    }
    return false;
}

int countryNodeSize(CountryNode countryNode) //Returns the amount of countries in countryNode
{
    CountryNode cn = countryGetFirst(countryNode);
    int size = 0;

    while (cn) {
        size++;
        cn = cn->next;
    }
    return size;
}

void countryNodePut(CountryNode countryNode,Country country) //Puts country inside the correct
{                                                            //place (via ID comparison) in countryNode
    //if country is first
    if (countryNodeSize(countryNode) == 0) {
        countryNode = (CountryNode)malloc(sizeof(struct CountryNode_t));
        countryNode->before = NULL;
        countryNode->next = NULL;
        countryNode->data = country;
        return;
    }

    CountryNode new_country_node = (CountryNode)malloc(sizeof(struct CountryNode_t));
    new_country_node->data = country;

    //If ID is before First
    CountryNode first = countryGetFirst(countryNode);
    if (*(first->data->ID) > *(country->ID)) {
        new_country_node->next = first;
        new_country_node->before = NULL;
        first->before = new_country_node;
        return;
    }

    //check if the country exists, and replace the data
    if (countryNodeExists(countryNode, *(country->ID))) {
        CountryNode cn = countryGetFirst(countryNode);
        while (cn) {
            if (*(cn->data->ID) == *(country->ID)) {
                cn->data = country;
                return;
            }
            cn = cn->next;
        }
    }

    //place it in its place
    CountryNode cn = countryGetFirst(countryNode);
    while (cn->next) { //cn->next so we wouldnt try to read from a null
        if (*(cn->data->ID) < *(country->ID) && *(cn->next->data->ID) > *(country->ID)) {
            cn->next->before = new_country_node;
            new_country_node->before = cn;
            new_country_node->next = cn->next;
            cn->next = new_country_node;
            return;
        }
    }

    //got here if countryNode should be last
    cn->next = new_country_node;
    new_country_node->before = cn;
}

bool checkInvalidName(const char *name) {
    int i = 0;
    while (*(name + i) != '\0') {
        if ((*(name + i) < 'a' || *(name + i) > 'z') && *(name + i) != ' ')
            return true;
        i++;
    }
    return false;
}

EurovisionResult eurovisionAddState(Eurovision eurovision, int stateId,
                                    const char *stateName,
                                    const char *songName)
{   //CHECK IF stateName IS VALID
    if (checkInvalidName(stateName))
        return EUROVISION_INVALID_NAME;
    //----
    //CHECK IF stateId IS POSITIVE
    if (stateId < 0)
        return EUROVISION_INVALID_ID;
    //----
    //CHECK IF THE SAME STATE EXIST
    if (countryNodeExists(eurovision->Countries, stateId))
        return EUROVISION_STATE_ALREADY_EXIST;
    //----

    Country state = (Country)malloc(sizeof(struct country_t));
    if (!state) {
        return EUROVISION_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    }

    state->ID = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(state->ID) = stateId;
    state->CountryName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(stateName) + 1);
    strcpy(state->CountryName, stateName);
    state->SongName = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(songName) + 1);
    strcpy(state->SongName, songName);

    countryNodePut(eurovision->Countries, state);

    /*  //TEST - DELETE THIS
    Country stateNew = countryNodeGet(eurovision->Countries, stateId);
    printf("eurovisionAddState: after mapPut-Cname=%s,Sname=%s,id=%d\n",(stateNew->CountryName), (stateNew->SongName), *(stateNew->ID));
    //----*/

    return EUROVISION_SUCCESS;
}

int main() {
    printf("Starting Test\n");
    Eurovision eurovision = setupEurovision();
    printf("After setupEurovision()\n");
    eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 1, "malta", "chameleon");
    printf("After eurovisionAddState of Malta\n");
    eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 2, "croatia", "the dream");
    eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 3, "russia", "scream");
    eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 4, "moldova", "stay");
    eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 5, "cyprus", "replay");
    eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 6, "spain", "la venda");
    eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 7, "italy", "soldi");
    eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 8, "france", "roi");
    eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 9, "germany", "sister");
    eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 10, "united kingdom", "bigger than us");
    eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 11, "armenia", "walking out");
    eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 12, "austria", "limits");
    eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 13, "ireland", "twenty two");
    eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 14, "netherlands", "arcade");
    eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 15, "sweden", "too late for love");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't even compile. Two functions are not declared before use and `checkInvalidName()` and `setupEurovision()` are not defined at all. Please read on how to create a [mcve]. Besides that, don't hide pointers behind `typedef`s and don't cast the result of `malloc()` and friends.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that function. Its now added.

Comment: And how is this now substantially different from the off-topic https://stackoverflow.com/q/55987751/918959

Comment: The code still doesn't compile, even in C89. You're using `<stdbool.h>` of C99 but implicit function definitions, the compiler spits out loads of diagnostics messages yet you mention none in the question.

Comment: In `countryGetFirst()` you dereference an invalid pointer value.

Comment: There is no main function.

Comment: Sorry!! Now everything should compile and the test should run.

Comment: Re-read my previous comment. *`while (cn->before)`* ... `cn` is invalid.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala it's substantially different because it's a post from a different user..............

Comment: @MartinJames so then we have a case of academic plagiarism too: two different persons having the **same code** and claiming it as their own. Because surely no one could be so devious as to actually circumvent the question ban by creating *another* user account.

Comment: It is funny, you just need to repost an off-topic question and suddenly it is answerable and gets upvotes.

Comment: **Why was this closed?** I understand that the code was less than complete at first, and @AnttiHaapala seems upset that the question was reposted after having been closed, but this version of the question seems to be in pretty good shape and was so for a good 10 hours prior to being closed. The code compiles, it's not overly long, and the problem is clear — what more do we want?

Comment: @Johnp For the record, it really looks like you created a new account in order to repost your question. Please know that that's considered very poor form around here, so avoid doing it in the future, okay? Welcome to Stack Overflow -- it's a great resource, and so much better when you go with the flow instead of against it. There are a lot of helpful tips in [help] and [tour] (and if you read through them you'll earn a badge). Stick around -- it's worth the small effort.

Comment: @Caleb it is still obvious that it is the full code, there is no attempt at [mcve]. Even the fact that the crash clearly occurs after the 14 last lines.

Answer (score 4):

> I have been trying to solve this with and without a debugger!

A debugger is an important tool for diagnosing this kind of thing, but you still have to think critically about what your code is doing in order to know what to look at with the debugger. A useful idea to keep in mind is that every crash is caused by some particular instruction<sup>*</sup>, and your job is to find that instruction and then figure out how you got there.

> I got this segmentation fault problem everytime I run this program

OK, so what instruction causes the segmentation fault? Your debugger should be able to point you to that line. Mine says the problem is here:

```
while (cn->before)
```

It also tells me how we got to that point and what the problem is:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
  * frame #0: 0x000000010000064c DeleteThis`countryGetFirst(cn=0x8b480850ff078b48) at main.c:65
    frame #1: 0x0000000100000688 DeleteThis`countryNodeExists(c=0x0000000102905f60, ID=1) at main.c:74
    frame #2: 0x0000000100000a1e DeleteThis`eurovisionAddState(eurovision=0x0000000102908750, stateId=1, stateName="malta", songName="chameleon") at main.c:182
    frame #3: 0x0000000100000b76 DeleteThis`main at main.c:212
    frame #4: 0x00007fff617253d5 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #5: 0x00007fff617253d5 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

(The "DeleteThis" is just the name I gave this project -- it's a reminder that I don't need to save this beyond the next 20 minutes. Also, I deleted some of your extra blank lines, so my line numbers probably won't match yours.)

The important thing here is that we're looking at the stack, and we can see that `countryGetFirst` was called by `countryNodeExists`, which was in turn called by `eurovisionAddState`, which was called from `main`. Okay, so next we need to know why the line in question crashed. A segmentation fault usually means that you're trying to dereference a bad pointer. Indeed, the line that crash *does* dereference some pointer, but is it bad? Let's figure out where it came from...

Your `main` function first sets up a variable `eurovision` like this:

```
Eurovision eurovision = setupEurovision();
```

So what does `setupEurovision` do? It just allocates some space for the Eurovision structure, and then allocates another block and makes `eurovision->Countries` point to it:

```
Eurovision euro=(Eurovision)malloc(sizeof(*euro));
euro->Countries=(CountryNode)malloc(sizeof(struct CountryNode_t));
return euro;
```

Looks okay so far, right? Next, what happens to that thing? Well, next you add a country:

```
eurovisionAddState(eurovision, 1, "malta", "chameleon");
```

To do that, `eurovisionAddState` calls:

```
if(countryNodeExists(eurovision->Countries,stateId))
```

That's interesting, because `eurovisionAddState` and `countryNodeExists` are both in the call stack when the crash happens, and you *just* allocated `eurovision->Countries`, so what happens if we look in `countryNodeExists`? Well, the first thing it does is to call the function that's crashing:

```
CountryNode cn = countryGetFirst(c);
```

and the `c` that it passes in here is exactly the `eurovision->Countries` in the caller. Hmmm... keep going. What's in `countryGetFirst`?

```
while (cn->before)
```

Hmmm. Why does that crash? The `cn` here was called `c` in the caller, which was `eurovision->Countries` in the previous caller, so we can trace `cn` all the way back to the `eurovision->Countries` from `main`. What do you think is in there? Remember, you created it like this:

```
(CountryNode)malloc(sizeof(struct CountryNode_t));
```

(Aside: you really shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`. Search here on SO to find out why.)

So, you created this thing with `malloc`. What's its value? You don't actually know what's in the block, you only know the block's address, and you haven't saved anything at that address yet. So, there are two possibilities: it's either zero, or it's nonzero. Odds are pretty good that it's nonzero, so what happens next? Well, you execute the body of the loop, so you do this:

```
cn = cn->before;
```

OK, so whatever was in the `before` member of this `CountryNode` is now in `cn`. Again, we don't know what was in the block, but it's pretty safe to assume that this `before` value isn't a pointer to another `CountryNode` because you haven't saved anything there yet. So now `cn` is some random value. You hit the end of the loop and, since it's a loop, you repeat:

```
while (cn->before)
```

Hmmm... now you're dereferencing that random value in `cn`, and at that point you get your segment fault because you're not allowed to read memory from just anywhere.

Now, I've walked you through this whole thing to illustrate the thought process. But you should be able to do the same thing with your debugger even if you don't understand the problem right off the bat... you can always set a breakpoint at some point that you know is before the problem, and then step through the instructions one at a time until you hit the error. You should do that now to help yourself really see and understand the issue. Once you do, I'm sure you'll be able to figure out how to fix it.

Good luck!

<sup>*</sup>Credit to Scott Knaster in his book [*How to Write Macintosh Software: The Debugging Reference for the Macintosh*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201608057) for this notion.

Comment: Oh, If we could only get more answers like this, it would dramatically cut down on the number of our "frequent fliers" asking different versions of the same thing over and over again... Well done.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words @DavidC.Rankin. Will you join me in voting to reopen this question? I think it'll be a useful debugging example for future readers.

Comment: Sure, I didn't see anything wrong with the question to begin with, other than it's length, but that wasn't unreasonable given the number of lines that were just enums and initialization. I have seen numerous questions closed in the last few months where the value of the answers clearly outweighed any defect in the question itself. Hopefully that too will pass.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few **dos** and **don'ts** for safer programming in C:

- **do** parenthesize macro arguments and expansions: `#define NOT_FOUND  (-1)`
- **don't** hide pointers behind typedefs: it makes the code more confusing and prone to errors.
- **don't** use pointers when a simple `int` member will suffice: `struct country_t { int ID; ...`
- **don't** cast the return value of `malloc()`
- **do** test if a list pointer is null before accessing its members: `countryGetFirst` will crash if `cn == NULL` (**this is your crash bug**)
- **do** learn to compile with debugging information and use a debugger with source code display, it would have pointed you to the problem immediately.
- **don't** use doubly linked lists when singly linked will suffice: you keep scanning the first node of each list, then scan the next nodes. Just make `eurovision->Countries` a pointer to the head of the list.
- **don't** use pointer notation `*(name + i)` when array notation is much more readable: `name[i]`
- **do** use `strdup()` to allocate copies of strings, rewrite it if it is not available on your system: `state->SongName = strdup(songName);`
- **do** test for memory allocation failure
- **do** use spaces around binary operators, after `,` and `;` and the `if`, `for`, `while` keywords, before `{` etc.
- **do** indent your code consistently. 4 spaces is a common readable convention.
- **don't** insert more than one blank line between code blocks and function definitions.
- **do** configure your compiler to issue extra warnings: `gcc -Wall -Wextra`...

Comment: common sense in action -:)