# Why does yyparse() causes my program to crash?

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

im making an assembler. Im using bison and flex to do so.
I Also have a C file in which I have my main function. But by some reason after the yyparse() function is called the progam crashes.

This is an example of my code. But it has the same outcome.

My lexer.l (lex) file

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%option nounput yylineno
%%
"sub"               return SUB;
";"                 return SEMICOLON;
.                   ;
[ \t]+              ;
%%
int yywrap()
{
    return 0;
}
```

My grammar.y (yacc) file.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void yyerror(const char *str)
{
        fprintf(stderr,"error: %s\n",str);
}

%}
%token SUB SEMICOLON
%%
commands: /* empty */
    | commands command
    ;

command:
    sub
    ;
sub:
    SUB SEMICOLON
    {
        printf("\tSub Detected\n");
    }
    ;
%%
```

My main.c file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int yyparse();
extern yy_scan_bytes ( const char *, int);
//My input buffer
char * memblock = "sub;\n";

int main()
{
    yy_scan_bytes(memblock, strlen(memblock));
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

Finally how I compile it.

```
bison -y -d grammar.y
flex lexer.l
gcc y.tab.c lex.yy.c -c
gcc main.c y.tab.o lex.yy.o
```

This is the outcome.

```
    Sub Detected

Segmentation fault
```

I would like to know how to fix the `Segmentation fault` error. Thanks.

Comment: Have you run the code in a debugger to see where the segfault is happening?  That is the 1st thing to do.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: It's good advice in general, but when working with lex/yacc, you would be looking at a bunch of machine-generated code that you didn't write and that wasn't written for humans to read.  So debugging may not be very helpful.

Comment: If you want to learn how to fault find the solution to this type of fault an excellent answer can be found at the last response on this thread:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55989470/trying-to-fix-segmentation-fault-in-a-c-program

Comment: While it's true that there's some generated code, especially for the Yacc rules, most of the generated stuff are still static data tables. Most of the code in the generated source files are actually inserted from other files, and as such trying to catch the crash in a debugger is still a good idea. If you build with debug information (add the `-g` flag when compiling all source files) it is possible to at the very least get some hints about what might be wrong, and then go on to search documentation for things like `yywrap` and what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your yywrap function is returning 0 (false == not yet wrapped up, more input needs to be read), but is not setting up the input, so when the scanner tries to read more data, it crashes.

Have yywrap return 1 (true) and you'll get an EOF and yyparser will return and all will be good.

Alternately, use `%option noyywrap` and get rid of it.